# How can I get a route given by the Directions API as a full set of LatLng pairs of coordinates?

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude, google-directions-api, google-polyline, turfjs

I want to calculate the minimum distance between a point and a polyline with JavaScript and [TurfJS](https://turfjs.org/). I can use the [pointToLineDistance function](https://turfjs.org/docs/#pointToLineDistance) for that, as follows:

```
var pt = turf.point([0, 0]);
var line = turf.lineString([[1, 1],[-1, 1]]);

var distance = turf.pointToLineDistance(pt, line, {units: 'miles'});
//=69.11854715938406
```

However, I want the LineString ('line') to be a route given by the Directions API. Therefore, I need to get the route as a set of LatLng coordinate pairs, such as:

```
var line = turf.lineString([
    [-77.031669, 38.878605],
    [-77.029609, 38.881946],
    [-77.020339, 38.884084],
    [-77.025661, 38.885821],
    [-77.021884, 38.889563],
    [-77.019824, 38.892368]
]);
```

[The set of pairs above would form this line over Washington, DC (ignore the two markers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IkSl.png)

**How can I get a route given by the Directions API as a full set of LatLng pairs?**

I tried reading through the API's documentation. You can [draw polylines from routes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex). Assuming the polylines are drawn based on the sets of coordinate pairs of a route, they must be in there, somewhere. I just couldn't find a way to get these sets from routes.

Comment: Have you searched before asking? I can find various Q/A providing viable solutions, with and without TurfJS.

Comment: *calculate the minimum distance between a point and a polyline* - please also clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve. You want the *closest point **on** the Polyline*? Or the closest *vertex*? Or the closest *segment*?